# Laravel automatic querybuilder from url

Tags: php, json, laravel

I want to make an automatic querybuilder that takes the params from the url in the controller and passes it on to my repository.

Now i have a set of keys/filters that the query can use to build its where clause, it matches the keys to the params in the url and it works. As long as I use only 1 key.

if I f.e. do :

```
".../api/v1/companies?is_accountant=0"  -->WORKS 
".../api/v1/companies?is_accountant=0&name=test&street=testLane -->FAILS, returns empty
```

The record exists in my DB, but it returns an empty object. If i try it seperatly with 1 key, it finds the record

Can someone spot the problem ?

```
private $filters = ['id','street','name','is_accountant','nr_ext','postal_code'];

    public function getCompaniesFilterd($params, $limit)
    {
        if (!empty($params)) {
            $query = Company::query();

            foreach($params as $param)
            {
                foreach($this->filters as $filter)
                {
                    if(key($params) == $filter)
                    {
                        $query->where($filter,'=',$param);
                    }
                }
            }
                      $companies = $query->get();
            dd($query);
            return $companies;
        }

        return Company::take(10)->get();
    }
```

output

```
{
"data": []
}
```

Query dump

```
object(Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder)[222]
  protected 'query' => 
    object(Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder)[221]
      protected 'connection' => 
        object(Illuminate\Database\MySqlConnection)[212]
          protected 'pdo' => 
            object(PDO)[181]
              ...
          protected 'readPdo' => null
          protected 'reconnector' => 
            object(Closure)[220]
              ...
          protected 'queryGrammar' => 
            object(Illuminate\Database\Query\Grammars\MySqlGrammar)[211]
              ...
          protected 'schemaGrammar' => null
          protected 'postProcessor' => 
            object(Illuminate\Database\Query\Processors\MySqlProcessor)[214]
              ...
          protected 'events' => 
            object(Illuminate\Events\Dispatcher)[14]
              ...
          protected 'paginator' => 
            object(Closure)[219]
              ...
          protected 'cache' => 
            object(Closure)[218]
              ...
          protected 'fetchMode' => int 8
          protected 'transactions' => int 0
          protected 'queryLog' => 
            array (size=1)
              ...
          protected 'loggingQueries' => boolean true
          protected 'pretending' => boolean false
          protected 'database' => string 'homestead' (length=9)
          protected 'tablePrefix' => string '' (length=0)
          protected 'config' => 
            array (size=9)
              ...
      protected 'grammar' => 
        object(Illuminate\Database\Query\Grammars\MySqlGrammar)[211]
          protected 'selectComponents' => 
            array (size=11)
              ...
          protected 'tablePrefix' => string '' (length=0)
      protected 'processor' => 
        object(Illuminate\Database\Query\Processors\MySqlProcessor)[214]
      protected 'bindings' => 
        array (size=5)
          'select' => 
            array (size=0)
              ...
          'join' => 
            array (size=0)
              ...
          'where' => 
            array (size=3)
              ...
          'having' => 
            array (size=0)
              ...
          'order' => 
            array (size=0)
              ...
      public 'aggregate' => null
      public 'columns' => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => string '*' (length=1)
      public 'distinct' => boolean false
      public 'from' => string 'companies' (length=9)
      public 'joins' => null
      public 'wheres' => 
        array (size=3)
          0 => 
            array (size=5)
              ...
          1 => 
            array (size=5)
              ...
          2 => 
            array (size=5)
              ...
      public 'groups' => null
      public 'havings' => null
      public 'orders' => null
      public 'limit' => null
      public 'offset' => null
      public 'unions' => null
      public 'lock' => null
      protected 'backups' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      protected 'cacheKey' => null
      protected 'cacheMinutes' => null
      protected 'cacheTags' => null
      protected 'cacheDriver' => null
      protected 'operators' => 
        array (size=19)
          0 => string '=' (length=1)
          1 => string '<' (length=1)
          2 => string '>' (length=1)
          3 => string '<=' (length=2)
          4 => string '>=' (length=2)
          5 => string '<>' (length=2)
          6 => string '!=' (length=2)
          7 => string 'like' (length=4)
          8 => string 'not like' (length=8)
          9 => string 'between' (length=7)
          10 => string 'ilike' (length=5)
          11 => string '&' (length=1)
          12 => string '|' (length=1)
          13 => string '^' (length=1)
          14 => string '<<' (length=2)
          15 => string '>>' (length=2)
          16 => string 'rlike' (length=5)
          17 => string 'regexp' (length=6)
          18 => string 'not regexp' (length=10)
  protected 'model' => 
    object(Winbooks\Core\Models\Company)[213]
      protected 'table' => string 'companies' (length=9)
      protected 'fillable' => 
        array (size=10)
          0 => string 'name' (length=4)
          1 => string 'street' (length=6)
          2 => string 'nr_ext' (length=6)
          3 => string 'postal_code' (length=11)
          4 => string 'city' (length=4)
          5 => string 'phone' (length=5)
          6 => string 'fax' (length=3)
          7 => string 'email' (length=5)
          8 => string 'is_accountant' (length=13)
          9 => string 'country_id' (length=10)
      protected 'connection' => null
      protected 'primaryKey' => string 'id' (length=2)
      protected 'perPage' => int 15
      public 'incrementing' => boolean true
      public 'timestamps' => boolean true
      protected 'attributes' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      protected 'original' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      protected 'relations' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      protected 'hidden' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      protected 'visible' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      protected 'appends' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      protected 'guarded' => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => string '*' (length=1)
      protected 'dates' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      protected 'touches' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      protected 'observables' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      protected 'with' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      protected 'morphClass' => null
      public 'exists' => boolean false
  protected 'eagerLoad' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  protected 'macros' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  protected 'onDelete' => null
  protected 'passthru' => 
    array (size=12)
      0 => string 'toSql' (length=5)
      1 => string 'lists' (length=5)
      2 => string 'insert' (length=6)
      3 => string 'insertGetId' (length=11)
      4 => string 'pluck' (length=5)
      5 => string 'count' (length=5)
      6 => string 'min' (length=3)
      7 => string 'max' (length=3)
      8 => string 'avg' (length=3)
      9 => string 'sum' (length=3)
      10 => string 'exists' (length=6)
      11 => string 'getBindings' (length=11)
```

Comment: You should not put `test` in quotes, unless the database entry is exactly like that (`"quotes"`). but the name is probably `test` and not `"test"`.

Comment: That was indeed problem N°1. Tried it without quotes, still doesn't work

Comment: does it fail or returns empty? these two things are NOT same.

Comment: ...With "doesn't work" meaning you're still getting an empty result? **Are you sure there is a matching record in your table?** Maybe you could update your question and also show the dump-output or maybe even the generated query.

Comment: sorry, little vage. it returns an empty result

Comment: Do you want it to be an OR or an AND between the wheres? the default is AND which may cause no record to match

Comment: I need it to be an AND

Comment: To get the generated SQL query, put this line before the  `$query->get();`: `\Event::listen('illuminate.query', function($sql) {var_dump($sql);});` . And once again the question: Are you absolutely sure there is a matching record in your table? `dd($query);` isn't really helpful, could you rather show the output of `dd($companies);`, please? And does it work if you pass e.g. *only* `name=test`?

Comment: this is a record in the db {
"data": [
{
"id": 1,
"name": "test1",
"street": "testLane",
"nr_ext": "",
"postal_code": "2100",
"city": "",
"fax": "",
"email": "",
"is_accountant": true
}
]
} ?id=1 WORKS // ?name=test1 WORKS   // ?id=1&name=test1 EMPTY

Comment: Well... The name is 'test1' and not 'test', and 'is_accountant' is true and not false / 0 - are you sure you're also passing the right values in your query string? Because in your question they're different. Sorry for the primitive questions, but more often than not the problem is really that simple and there's just a missing dot, quote or semicolon... :) As mentioned above, maybe it would help seeing the raw generated SQL query.

Comment: the above was a new example, And it does say test1. The is_accountant is saved as a integer that i transform to a boolean. I'd like to see the generated sql query to, but it is so deeply embedded in my query object. Is there an easier way to get it out ?

Comment: Ok... Does it work if you just build the query yourself? E.g. `Company::where('id', 1)->where('name', 'test1')->get();`? If so, what's the output of `dd($params)`?

Comment: if i do the query string myself it does work. I also took the params that were given in the url. So it the problem lies with the build of my query not the DB or the params. Been staring at it for over 3 hours, can't find the issue

Comment: try to get the SQL. In the query builder object, use `toSql()`. like `return $query->toSql()`. it will give the query that has ran. you are dumping the whole object. it won't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to reporoduce this behaviour with your code, but I'm not exactly sure what causes it. The error seems to be that the filter-values don't change, there's probably some weird issue with the loops. So I'd like to take this as an occasion to rewrite and improve your code a little, since I think Laravel allows for a way more elegant way of doing this.

```
private $filters = ['id','street','name','is_accountant','nr_ext','postal_code'];

public function getCompaniesFiltered($params, $limit = 10)
{
    $params = array_diff_key($params, $this->filters);

    if(empty($params))
    {
        return Company::take($limit)->get();
    }

    return Company::where($params)->get();
}
```

Just calling it with `getCompaniesFiltered(Input::all());` worked fine for me.

**EDIT:**
After looking a little closer at the loops, I'm pretty sure the  problem is just one additional 's':

```
if(key($params) == $filter)
```

should be

```
if(key($param) == $filter)
```

`if (1 == 'name')` (or comparing booleans, strings and some ints) can result in a pretty weird behaviour in PHP.

---

**EDIT 2:**

*Note*: Please do not ask separate question under the same topic. Even though they are related, they are still different questions, but you should give the one who answers them the change to get the credit for both. Since you seem to be new at StackOverflow, let's just leave it at that for now, but please keep that in mind for your future questions.

The ansewers:

> *"If i use your previous suggestion it worked, but i just came to notice that if you enter a wrong param is still wants to search the table --> resulting in a Error Row in table not found."*

Right, `array_diff` was not the best choice here, it should be:

```
$params = array_intersect_key($params, array_flip($this->filters))
```

> *"I'm trying to query like before, but now i also want to be able to put params on my related models."*

Again, Laravel makes this really easy with Eloquent's [eager loading concept](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#eager-loading). The class could look like this:

```
private $mainFilters = ['id', 'name', 'preview','user_id', 'date', 'status'];
private $fileFilters =  ['path', 'uuid'];
private $invoicesFilters = ['due_date', 'payment_status', 'type'];

public function getDocumentsFiltered($params, $limit = 10)
{
    $dependencies = $this->getDependencies($params);
    $documentParams = $this->filterParams($params, $this->mainFilters));

    $documents = Document::with($dependencies);

    if(empty($documentParams))
    {
        return $documents->take($limit)->get();
    }

    return $docuemnts->where($documentParams)->get();
}

protected function getDependencies($params)
{
   $fileParams = $this->filterParams($params, $this->fileFilters));
   $invoiceParams = $this->filterParams($params, $this->invoiceFilters));

   return [
       'file' => function($query) use ($fileParams) {
           $query->where($fileParams);
       },

       'invoice' => function($query) use ($invoiceParams) {
           $query->where($invoiceParams);
       },

       'user',
       'folder',
   ];
}

protected function filterParams($input, $filter)
{
    return array_intersect_key($input, array_flip($filter);
}
```

The code is not commented, but I think it pretty much explains itself.

Comment: THANK YOU !! Your solution worked. About the if statement, the key method expects an array to be given. $param is a string, so that won't work. THANK YOU again

Comment: @Nsmet Ok, so it was a simple associative array and not a nested array. In that case, if you want to work with the key, you can extract it in the foreach statement: `foreach($params as $param => $value)`, and then `if($param == $filter) { $query->where($param, $value) };` That would have sevaed you a lot of headache ;)

Comment: I've got a simular question to the one above. How can I do a where clause with my params on underlying models? The full question is below

Answer (score 0):

@Quasdunk Your last answer was indeed the better choice/answer. If i use your previous suggestion it worked, but i just came to notice that if you enter a wrong param is still wants to search the table --> resulting in a Error Row in table not found.

This is my final code

```
private $filters = ['id', 'name', 'date', 'status'];

public function getDocumentListFilterd($params, $limit = 10)
{

    if (!empty($params)) {
        $query = Document::query();

        foreach($params as $param => $value)
        {

            foreach($this->filters as $filter)
            {

                if($param == $filter)
                {
                    $query->where($filter,'=',$value);
                }
            }
        }
        $documents = $query->get();
        //dd($query);
        return $documents;
    }

    return Company::take(10)->get();

 }
```

Comment: I've edited my answer accordingly, but once again the note: Please do not ask multiple questions in a singe question-thread and do not use answers for discussion or to ask other questions. Each question should be asked separately, even if they are related, they represent different problems.